# Making WiFi hotspot for 3G network sharing controlled by Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, wifi

I am trying to make a WiFi internet network from 3G using Arduino as access control. I need the Arduino to act as server and control users, consumption, and connection speed. (When users connect to the WiFi, they have to enter a passcode in a webpage to use internet for a limited time,  or limited data.)

So is this possible? I still did not try anything because I can not afford to buy many objects and fail to make it work.

I am thinking of using a 3G shield and a WiFi shield, or a router connected to 3G dongle connected to an Arduino via ethernet, or a 3G shield Arduino to ethernet shield to WiFi router.

I don't know if any of these can work, so I really appreciate any guidance.

Answer (score 4):

Not a chance, I am afraid (you were right not to buy things yet). Things like the 3G shield and WiFi shield don't work in the way that is needed for a WiFi hotspot like that. You're better off with a Raspberry Pi and a 3G USB dongle and run `hostapd` along with the other software needed for your project - things like apache, etc.

You may be able to do it with the Linux portion (OpenWRT) of an Arduino Yun with a USB 3G dongle attached, but it would be sluggish. Best to stick to something with enough processing to do what you want, which means a Raspberry Pi or similar.

Answer (score 0):

What you want (on at least an ARM board) is a captive portal, which catches and releases new users if and only if they pass the required challenge. There are numerous software packages for this. If you use a pi, and need to do something with the GPIO pons, have a look at the WiringPi project, which is much nicer than python's silliness. 'Inspired by Monty Python' ... indeed.